# Storing values in python

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Trying to write a program that will split data off text files and than let me do calculations and displaying the data.  The grid that I'm bringing in the data from is 144x73, this will cover many days/years so it not a simple single dimensional store of data.

What I'm working with right now...

```
a = open('filename.txt','r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()

d = 0
i = () # don't think this is the correct approach by a long shot but something I decided to try when [] wasn't giving me what I hoped for
for e in range(11, 84): # first eleven lines of each file are not part of the data
    f = b[e]
    f = f.replace('.0000', '')
    f = f.replace('   ', '')
    f = f.replace(' ', ',')
    c = 0
    h = f[c*1] + f[(c*1)+1] + f[(c*1)+2] + f[(c*1)+3] # needs to combine each of the 4 characters between the commas from above
    i(d,0).append(int(h)) # definitely not the correct way to store the data
    c = c + 4
    for g in range(1,143):
        h = f[(c*1)+1] + f[(c*1)+2] + f[(c*1)+3] + f[(c*1)+4]
        i(d,g).append(int(h))
        c = c + 5
     print(i(d,0),i(d,1),i(d,2))
     d = d + 1
     continue
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because I'm not sure how to go about storing the value each time it pulls the value from the file.  It pulls the data correctly and combines/converts it into and integer but I can't figure out how to best store the data.  I'm not what the correct/best approach is.

I can see a format necessary being:
a = ???Year, date, column, row???

??? indicating I'm not sure if I should be putting the focus toward (, [ or [[.

273.82001       273.82001       273.87000       273.90002       273.91998       273.95001       274.00000       274.02002       274.04999       274.10001       274.12000       274.10001       274.15002       274.15002       274.15002       274.16998       274.20001       274.16998       274.16998       274.16998       274.16998       274.15002       274.12000       274.12000       274.12000       274.10001       274.10001       274.07001       274.04999       274.04999       274.04999       274.02002       274.00000       274.00000       273.97000       273.97000       274.02002       274.02002       274.02002       274.00000       273.97000       273.97000       273.97000       273.95001       273.95001       273.95001       273.95001       273.97000       273.95001       273.90002       273.90002       273.90002       273.90002       273.87000       273.85001       273.85001       273.85001       273.82001       273.79999       273.79999       273.79999       273.77002       273.79999       273.79999       273.79999       273.77002       273.79999       273.79999       273.79999       273.82001       273.82001       273.87000       273.85001       273.87000       273.87000       273.90002       273.91998       273.91998       273.95001       273.97000       273.95001       273.95001       274.00000       274.00000       274.00000       274.02002       274.02002       274.04999       274.04999       274.04999       274.04999       274.07001       274.07001       274.04999       274.04999       274.04999       274.07001       274.07001       274.04999       274.04999       274.02002       274.02002       274.02002       274.02002       274.02002       274.00000       274.00000       273.97000       273.95001       273.95001       273.97000       273.97000       273.95001       273.95001       273.95001       273.91998       273.91998       273.91998       273.90002       273.90002       273.90002       273.90002       273.87000       273.85001       273.85001       273.79999       273.79999       273.77002       273.77002       273.72000       273.70001       273.75000       273.72000       273.70001       273.70001       273.66998       273.66998       273.66998       273.70001       273.70001       273.72000       273.72000       273.75000       273.79999

274.02002       274.12000       274.22000       274.37000       274.45001       274.57001       274.65002       274.75000       274.85001       274.85001       274.90002       274.91998       274.95001       274.87000       274.85001       274.79999       274.70001       274.60001       274.50000       274.35001       274.22000       274.10001       273.97000       273.82001       273.70001       273.60001       273.45001       273.35001       273.27002       273.20001       273.15002       273.12000       273.10001       273.12000       273.15002       273.16998       273.22000       273.27002       273.37000       273.41998       273.52002       273.60001       273.65002       273.78000       273.85001       273.90002       273.95001       273.97000       274.02002       274.02002       274.04999       274.04999       274.07001       274.04999       274.02002       274.00000       273.97000       273.97000       273.95001       273.90002       273.90002       273.85001       273.82001       273.82001       273.82001       273.82001       273.82001       273.85001       273.87000       273.87000       273.90002       273.91998       273.95001       273.97000       274.00000       274.00000       274.02002       274.00000       274.00000       273.97000       273.91998       273.91998       273.90002       273.85001       273.82001       273.77002       273.78000       273.77002       273.75000       273.77002       273.85001       273.90002       273.95001       274.04999       274.15002       274.25000       274.35001       274.47000       274.60001       274.66998       274.79999       274.87000       274.91998       274.97000       275.00000       275.07001       275.07001       275.07001       275.10001       275.12000       275.15002       275.16998       275.22000       275.28000       275.29999       275.35001       275.37000       275.41998       275.45001       275.47000       275.50000       275.45001       275.41998       275.37000       275.29999       275.22000       275.10001       274.97000       274.87000       274.72000       274.57001       274.41998       274.29999       274.15002       274.02002       273.95001       273.85001       273.82001       273.77002       273.75000       273.78000       273.78000       273.87000       273.91998

274.22000       274.27002       274.35001       274.35001       274.41998       274.50000       274.52002       274.60001       274.65002       274.65002       274.70001       274.72000       274.70001       274.66998       274.70001       274.62000       274.54999       274.47000       274.40002       274.29999       274.16998       274.04999       273.91998       273.78000       273.65002       273.52002       273.41998       273.28000       273.16998       273.04999       272.95001       272.82001       272.75000       272.70001       272.66998       272.66998       272.70001       272.77002       272.79999       272.90002       273.03000       273.16998       273.27002       273.35001       273.47000       273.57001       273.65002       273.70001       273.72000       273.77002       273.77002       273.75000       273.77002       273.75000       273.70001       273.70001       273.70001       273.72000       273.70001       273.70001       273.75000       273.79999       273.82001       273.87000       273.91998       273.97000       274.02002       274.07001       274.12000       274.20001       274.22000       274.25000       274.27002       274.29999       274.27002       274.29999       274.29999       274.22000       274.20001       274.15002       274.07001       274.03000       273.95001       273.82001       273.72000       273.65002       273.54999       273.45001       273.40002       273.40002       273.41998       273.52002       273.66998       273.90002       274.15002       274.50000       274.85001       275.20001       275.54999       275.85001       276.10001       276.29999       276.50000       276.60001       276.62000       276.65002       276.62000       276.62000       276.57001       276.57001       276.57001       276.60001       276.65002       276.66998       276.77002       276.75000       276.77002       276.75000       276.65002       276.54999       276.40002       276.20001       275.97000       275.75000       275.50000       275.27002       275.07001       274.87000       274.75000       274.57001       274.47000       274.40002       274.35001       274.32001       274.29999       274.27002       274.27002       274.22000       274.22000       274.22000       274.22000       274.16998       274.20001       274.25000

I can't figure out how to get this to allow me to format it the way it actually appears, but does have the extra spaces between each number, hence why I remove them with the above code.  Each column is separated by spaces and each row is separated(in this case) by double carriage return.

From the above I can easily turn each line into a separate line but I haven't figured out how to store the line.

A rough idea of the output.  I do know this is going to even change since more ideas keep coming up all the time.  Roughly I need a way of being able to keep track of the year, month/day, what the value represents, values.  It's a matter of having so many rows/columns for each that makes this seem more complicated than what even I think it truly is.  My mind is just trying to complicate something that is simple.

1948,0101,500T,1234,4234,2344,3242,1485,(144 columns in total)(row 0)
1948,0101,500T,1342,1243,1446,5453,6623,(144 columns in total)(row 1)

1948,0101,(rows 2-73)

1948,0102,500T,1623,2534,2434,3242,1845,(144 columns in total)(row 0)
1948,0102,500T,1352,5123,1432,5473,9623,(144 columns in total)(row 1)

1948,0102,(rows 2-73)

1949,0101,1000P,4353,2346,5257,3345,1274,8756,(144 columns in total)(row 0)
1949,0101,1000P,5734,2244,1556,7657,3452,6743,(144 columns in total)(row 1)

1949,0101,(rows 2-73)
etc to end of files being added to list.

The year, month/day, data origin(500T/1000P) would be added from me not from the file(aka the filename which is labeled according to date and what the file contains)

What is the best way of handling this.  I don't think even back in my old basic/VB days I did anything quite this complex:)

Edit:
The hoped for intention is to have everything stored by date.  I would like to have each row of data kept separate(granted I am starting to think of bundling them and making it much simpler, granted 144*73 with each data is a lot elements to keep space on, aka row 0 starts at 0, row 1 starts at 144, row 2 starts at 288, row 2 starts at 432,etc within the array.  I have figured I could do that, here this morning.  I was hoping for 'ease of things' to instead be able to do something...

want to bring up the column 5, on the 6th row of data for a given date and given metric(all dates are separate files and all metrics are separate file, so you could easily have 4-10 files for the same date)

```
data[1948,1,1,1,6,5]
```

from above
1948 is obviously the year, 1 is the month, 1 is the date, 1 is the metric, 6 is the row, 5 is the column

Yeah, I haven't been the best with my description I should have did the above originally, now I realize it like a dummy.  Sorry, where is the hammer hitting the head emocon.

Comment: Please show us a shortened version of your input (only a few lines) and the expected output.

Comment: Okay, just added in the sample input.  The output doesn't match the input as I just left that alone, other than to add in the data origin from what I initially posted.

Comment: So you want to prepend the 73 lines with the year, month, etc., then increment the date and prepend them again for each day of the year? Or do you have a lot of different files which are associated with a date and you want to add this date to the lines? More context please.

Comment: I think the update this time is much better.  Sometimes your mind can't think fast enough to make things simple when you post the initial posting.